# Rock Paper Scissors game Javascript, how to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, html

Currently doing a rock paper scissors tutorial and can't see where I forgot to do something because the userChoice and the computerChoice are showing, but still the result doesn't show up.
I'm currently learning and really can't figure out where is my mistake

```
const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice')
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('user-choice')
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('resut')

const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let computerChoice
let userChoice
let result
possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    userChoice = e.target.id
    userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
    generateComputerChoice()
    getResult()
}))

function generateComputerChoice(){
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChoices.length) + 1 //or 3
    

    if (randomNumber === 1) {
        computerChoice='rock'
    }
    if (randomNumber === 2){
        computerChoice='scissors'
    }
    if (randomNumber === 3){
        computerChoice='paper'
    }
    computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice
}

function getResult(){
    if (computerChoice === userChoice){
        result = 'its a draw!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === 'paper'){
        result = 'you win!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === 'scissors'){
        result = 'you lost!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === 'scissors'){
        result = 'you win!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === 'rock'){
        result = 'you lost!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === 'rock'){
        result = 'you win!'
    }
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === 'paper'){
        result = 'you lost!'
    }
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}
```

Comment: Any chance this is just a typo? Your line "const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('resut')" has "result" misspelled. If your element's ID is actually "result," then this could explain the issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you mistyped the ID, you'll get an error saying that you can't set `innerHTML` of `null`

Comment: And if you haven't checked the console, why not? That should be the first place you look when trying to debug a JavaScript problem.

Comment: I agree with @EvanBaldonado about the misspelled ID. Sometimes when I debug my code, it is because of a typo. What I may ask is why aren't there semicolons? I really do not think JavaScript works without semicolons.

Comment: @Major_Flux- Javascript doesn't technically require semicolons due to automatic semicolon insertion (ASI), although it is good practice to use them.

Comment: @EvanBaldonado I see that now. But I still will write my code with semicolons.